# How to create Spring Cloud Config Client with env specific configuration?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-config

I have facing an issue with Spring Cloud Config Server and Eureka Server Profiling.
Let's say I have 3 services with their name ("spring.application.name") as :

```
myapp-svc
myapp-spring-cloud-config-svc
myapp-spring-eureka-svc
```

I want to deploy each service in 2 regions ( dev and prod ). In Dev region, each service will run on localhost and in prod it will have some different url.    'myapp-spring-cloud-config-svc' in dev region will point to local git repo, while in prod region it will point to remote git repo.I can have 2 configurations:

1)  When I start 'myapp-svc' service in local, it should connect to 'myapp-spring-cloud-config-svc' in dev. 
      I can do this by setting spring.cloud.config.uri = .
      But the issue with this set up is that the property needs to be defined in bootstrap.properties. 
      So, If deploy 'myapp-svc'  to prod, I will have to change config uri there to point it to prod config service which in turn would need another build creation.
      This doesn't seem like a good solution, what if I have 50 app related services, I can't change this property in each one of them before prod deployment.
      I tried setting spring.cloud.config.uri in application-dev.properties of 'myapp-svc' but it doesn't work. As per docs, it must be changed in bootstrap.

```
  So, how do I implement this without having to create new build for prod ?
```

2) I can first call eureka and then using eureka I can call config service here.
       The problem here is also same.
       If I use eureka to look up config then "eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone" must be defined in "bootstrap.yml".
       See this:https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_client.html
So, in this case too, I need to change eureka url before deploying this service to prod.
Please help me on this...!!
  Here is how, the properties, yml looks like for each of the above mentioned services:

```
1) myapp-svc:
   1.1)bootstrap.yml  
        spring:
         application:
           name: myapp-svc 
         cloud:
           config:
             discovery:
               enabled: true
               serviceId: myapp-spring-cloud-config-svc
        eureka:
           client:
              serviceUrl:
                defaultZone: http://localhost:8762/eureka/
        server:
           port: 8082


    2) myapp-spring-cloud-config-svc:

      2.1)application-dev.properties:
           spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:///C:/config-repo
           eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8762/eureka

      2.2)application-prod.properties:
           spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/<mygit Repo>

      2.3)bootstrap.proerties:
           spring.application.name=myapp-spring-cloud-config-svc
           server.port=8888


    3) myapp-spring-eureka-svc
       3.1)bootstrap.proerties
        spring.application.name=myapp-spring-eureka-svc
        server.port=8762
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) You can have profile specific `bootstrap-<profile>.properties` (like for `application-<profile>.properties`) for each supported profile to avoid rebuilding your application for each env. Then just pass application profile using to your application during start-up. Spring will load correct `bootstrap-<profile>.properties` and will connect to proper configuration server (or eureka, etc). Example:

```
java -jar your-app.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev
```

2) You can pass your URLs externally as custom properties (same as with profile above) and have smth like this in `bootstrap.properties`. Example:

```
spring.cloud.config.uri=${config.server.url}
```

then pass `--config.server.url= ...` during start-up.

3) You can pass Spring properties in the same way during start-up. Example:

```
java -jar your-app.jar --spring.cloud.config.uri= ...
```

4) You can use system env variables. Example:

```
spring.cloud.config.uri=${SYSTEM_ENV_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI}
```

Comment: Thanks nmyk. It is picking up files based on profile. I had tried this before but it didn't work earlier, now that I looked into it again, I came to know the reason. Which brings me to this question: If I add a file in local repo and commit it, and start a service, the service is cloning the remote repo thus overriding my changes in local repo. How can I stop this behavior ? Every time, it is refreshing from remote and deleting any files  added in my local repo. spring.cloud.config.server.git.force-pull= false also doesn't make any difference, although as per docs, this is by default false.

Comment: I know, ppl have suggested to use 'native' profile to read from local repo. But I have configured local repo for Dev profile, so is there any work around for this ?

Comment: @adwived I had the same issue with refreshing from remote. So I see 2 work arounds (maybe mot perfect, but...)
1. use native and set spring.cloud.config.server.native.search-locations=file:///C:/config-repo, and pass 2 profiles --spring.profiles.active=dev,native
2. use remote repo, and have some sandbox branch where you can quickly commit without any code-reviews, in this case you will need to set spring.cloud.config.label=your_branch for config clients to fetch last configuration during developing

Comment: @adwived If I answered your main question please accept it according to StackOverflow recommendations to help others, thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Option 4 is all I need.